# Python; csv writer must start on new line

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a script that uses os.walk and I want to add the current working directories on the first line of the output file. I included os.path.realpath to my code to get the current working directory, but the following command of csv.writer adds the output on the first row, so directly after my directory text and I want csv.writer to start on a new line, not on the first line. I know that I can add "/n' to start on a new line, but how do I add to the os.path.realpath command? 
Thanks

```
import os
import csv
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict


def get_file_values(find_files, output_name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        if all(x in files for x in find_files):
            outputs = []
            for f in find_files:
                d = {}
                with open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r') as f1:
                    for line in f1:
                        ta = line.split()
                        d[ta[1]] = int(ta[0])
                outputs.append(d)

            d3 = defaultdict(list)
            for k, v in chain(*(d.items() for d in outputs)):
                d3[k].append(v)

            with open(os.path.join(root, output_name), 'w+') as fnew:
                fnew.write(os.path.realpath(root))
                writer = csv.writer(fnew)
                for k, v in d3.items():
                    writer.writerow([k] + v)

get_file_values(['genes.gff.genespercontig.csv', 'hmmer.analyze.txt.results.txt'], 'output_contigsvsgenes.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.realpath()` returns a string, just append a newline to that:

```
fnew.write(os.path.realpath(root) + '\n')
```